# Convert SAML metadata xml into OneLogin parameters

Tags: xml, single-sign-on, saml, onelogin

I'm a service provider(SP) and we have customers(IDP) who give us their SAML metadata xml file. We then want to input into our database the requisite parameters for OneLogin to enable SAML SSO.

Is there an easy way to pull out SP OneLogin SAML parameters from an IDP metadata xml?

The parameters we are looking to easily extract are:

- idp_entity_id
- idp_sso_target_url
- idp_slo_target_url
- idp_cert
- name_identifier_format
- authn_requests_signed
- logout_requests_signed
- logout_responses_signed
- metadata_signed
- digest_method
- signature_method

FYI - we are using the ruby-saml OneLogin library: https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could

```
  idp_metadata_parser = OneLogin::RubySaml::IdpMetadataParser.new
   # Returns OneLogin::RubySaml::Settings prepopulated with idp metadata
  settings = idp_metadata_parser.parse_remote("https://example.com/auth/saml2/idp/metadata")
```

And then extract the attributes from the 'settings'.